# How to plot a data table of 0's and 1's as a two-color grid in R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have some files like the one below. Each contains 26 lines, which consist of a sample name and a number of 0's and 1's.

```
mem/Bur_05_sorted.bam_A 0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
mem/Bur_05_sorted.bam_B 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Ell_06_sorted.bam_A 1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Ell_06_sorted.bam_B 0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Ell_07_sorted.bam_A 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Ell_07_sorted.bam_B 1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Ste_01_sorted.bam_A 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Ste_01_sorted.bam_B 0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Sto_02_sorted.bam_A 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
mem/Sto_02_sorted.bam_B 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Sto_03_sorted.bam_A 1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Sto_03_sorted.bam_B 0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
mem/Sto_07_sorted.bam_A 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Sto_07_sorted.bam_B 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_01_sorted.bam_A 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_01_sorted.bam_B 0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_02_sorted.bam_A 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_02_sorted.bam_B 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_03_sorted.bam_A 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_03_sorted.bam_B 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_04_sorted.bam_A 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_04_sorted.bam_B 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_05_sorted.bam_A 1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_05_sorted.bam_B 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
mem/Vog_06_sorted.bam_A 1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
mem/Vog_06_sorted.bam_B 1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The lines represent genome sequences of an individual of admixed ancestry. Each number represents a bin of length 0.01 megabases, the value denotes the ancestry of the binned segment.
I'd like to use this file to produce a grid-like plot in two colors (0's in red and 1's in blue for example), where the y-axis shows the samplenames. A plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkdLC.png).

I am not experienced in R, but my initial guess was to read the table as a matrix:

```
data <- as.matrix(read.table("L_1616.vit.txt"), rownames = 1)
```

And then use image() to plot. But I can't quite figure out what to provide as arguments for this command.
Anybody who can explain how to do this? Is image() the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following example. Based , on your code, removing `as.matrix` when you load the dataset should make you be able to obtain a similar structure)

```r
df <- data.frame(row.names = LETTERS[1:20],
                 col1 = sample(c(0,1),20, replace = TRUE),
                 col2 = sample(c(0,1),20, replace = TRUE),
                 col3 = sample(c(0,1),20, replace = TRUE))  

> head(df)
  col1 col2 col3
A    0    1    0
B    1    1    1
C    1    0    0
D    0    1    0
E    0    1    0
F    0    0    1
```

Using `image`, you can do:

```r
image(as.matrix(df), col = c("red","blue"))
```

[image]

However, an another option coul be to make a plot using `ggplot2` and `geom_tile` function.

You can pivot the dataframe into a longer format using `pivot_longer` and get the following daatset:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Row = rownames(df)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Row)

# A tibble: 60 x 3
   Row   name  value
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 A     col1      0
 2 A     col2      1
 3 A     col3      0
 4 B     col1      1
 5 B     col2      1
 6 B     col3      1
 7 C     col1      1
 8 C     col2      0
 9 C     col3      0
10 D     col1      0
# … with 50 more rows
```

In addition to the previous code, you can pass the follwoign code to get the plot:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% mutate(Row = rownames(df)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Row) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Row, y = reorder(name, desc(name)), fill = as.factor(value)))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Code", values = c("red","blue"))+
  labs(y = "")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: That was VERY helpful! Thanks a lot!